# Laravel - Package extend layout from parent project

Tags: php, laravel, package

I recently made a package which has a default route, controller and view. I uploaded the package to packagist and required it using `composer require package/name` and it all works fine. However I want the view in the package to use a layout that is set in the parent project.

**Main project**

My main project has a layout file in `resources/views/layouts/layouts/backend.blade.php` and I want the package to extend that specific layout. Is that possible?

**Package**

*Controller*

```
 public function index()
 {
   return view('visitors::home');
 }
```

*Route*

`Route::get('dashboard/visitors', '\Rainieren\Visitors\Http\Controllers\VisitorController@index')->name('visitors');`

*View*

```
<h1>Visitors page</h1>
```

I tried doing `@extend('layouts.layouts.backend')` but unfortunately that does not work. How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can give a look at the side of the publishing views.
Once published they will be in 'resources/views/vendor/packageName'.
And your view will have access to the 'resources/views' folder.

Example from (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/packages#views)

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/courier'),
    ]);
}
```

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, this is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. I want the package to extend a layout from the parent. Not the parent from the package.

Comment: Okay, misunderstanding on my part. You need to publish the views of your package. I've edited the answer